# id element positions in an array with duplicated value java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array with duplicated data and need to ID each data positions in this array. Is there a way to achieve that?

For example: `Double [] array = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 100};` Is there a way for Java to tell there is one 100 in index 0 and another one is in index 5?

I tried to use loop but realized the loop always starts from the first one.

```
private int getArrayIndex(double[] navdata, double data) {

     int k = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i < navdata.length; i++){

            if(navdata[i] == data){

                k=i;
                break;
            }
        }

    return k;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your loop starts from the 0 index, because you are using i = 0 as initial index, using break causes that the loop ends at the firsts value of data is found.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should return a **List of index** and **not just one index** so instead your solution should be :

```
private List<Integer> getArrayIndex(double[] navdata, double data) {
//------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < navdata.length; i++) {
        if (navdata[i] == data) {
            result.add(i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
private List<Integer> getArrayIndexJava8(double[] navdata, double data) {
    return IntStream.range(0, navdata.length).boxed()
            .filter(index -> navdata[index] == data)
            .collect(toList());
}
```

An example :

```
System.out.println(mcve.getArrayIndex(array, 100));
=>[0, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the indices of the array that matches the value found in query.

```
private int[] getIndices(double[] array, double query) {
    return IntStream.range(0, array.length)
        .filter(index -> array[index] == query)
        .toArray();
}
```